# How to remove "touch event listener"

Tags: javascript, html, events

I tick to "Scroll Performance Issues" on Dev Tools of Chrome. It shows me that is something is wrong with Touch Event Listener.

How can I remove it?
By default, some events are added automatically to some special element like "a", "button", so how could I remove them.

[image]

Comment: @MathiasFalci: Before I add new question I have already checked old questions, so I don't think my question is duplicated. My question is: some events are added automatically to some special element like "a", "button", so how could I remove them?

Comment: I'm sorry, now I understand, unfortunately I don't know how to remove these default events, hope someone can help you.